# Connecting Power BI to Cognos

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence, cognos, cognos-tm1

I'm brand new to Power BI. I am wondering if it is possible (and if so, is it easy?) to connect PowerBI to TM1 cubes and other cubes ( Dynamic, Transformer) in Cognos. Can't find a clear answer anywhere else.

Thanks.

Comment: TM1Py base on Python will help you to do it easily for TM1 cubes. After for the others kind of cubes check on the API sides. You'll surely find things and parse these API to get datas in PowerBI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lists the data sources https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-data-sources

The one of interest is the BI Connector,  looks like you can buy one to connect to Cognos 
https://senturus.com/resources/use-power-bi-with-trusted-cognos-data/

Answer (score 0):

While TM1 creates In Memory cubes there must be an application server serving the tm1 cube. Probably the easiest way to connect is to use the IBM Cognos API or SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily connect Power Bi to TM1 cubes with Python.
Here is a like where the you can find how to do it :
[click this tlink](https://code.cubewise.com/tm1py-help-content/getting-tm1-data-into-power-bi)

https://code.cubewise.com/tm1py-help-content/getting-tm1-data-into-power-bi